# choose same file in path list file in another path list file

Tags: python, list, path

I have a list of path file

```
image_list1 = ['/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Match/bed/2.jpg','/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Match/bed/4.jpg']
```

and

```
image_list1=['/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Match/chairs/4.jpg','/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Match/chairs/3.jpg','/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Match/chairs/2.jpg','/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Match/chairs/1.jpg']
```

what is the code How I can create another list like this line

```
image_list3=['/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Match/chairs/2.jpg','/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Match/chairs/4.jpg']
```

I have two folders beds and chairs?

Comment: Why can you not use the third line of code you have shown, which creates the list you want?

Comment: thanks for ur time, that's what I want to do but I don't know the code to do third line

Comment: So you want to get specific chairs if number is found in list of beds?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```py
bed_list = [
    "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Match/bed/2.jpg",
    "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Match/bed/4.jpg",
]

chair_list = [
    "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Match/chairs/4.jpg",
    "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Match/chairs/3.jpg",
    "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Match/chairs/2.jpg",
    "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Match/chairs/1.jpg",
]

tmp = {i.rsplit("/", maxsplit=1)[-1] for i in bed_list}

out = [i for i in chair_list if i.rsplit("/", maxsplit=1)[-1] in tmp]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Match/chairs/4.jpg",
    "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Match/chairs/2.jpg",
]
```

Comment: why when the first list contains more than 2 elements the output list contain just two elements?